# How do I find my website's SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I do not know how to find the SSL Certificate on the File System for the website I am working on. Someone else put it in and I cannot find it. Also, how do I get the URL for it?

Comment: Are you asking where to find the certificate file on the File System, or are interested in just viewing the certificate properties through a browser, for example?

Comment: On the file system. My apologies for not being more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Apache:

1. Move to Apache sites enabled folder (/etc/apache/sites-enabled)
2. Open each file in this folder
3. You have to find **the tag SSLCertificateFile**
4. Browse to SSLCertificateFile path